# Show TipKit tips in SwiftUI Preview

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I'm using TipKit.

How can I have my tips show up in the SwiftUI preview?

```
#Preview {
    SettingEditView(editValue: .constant(DialogSetting(name: "Test Setting")))
}
```

`SettingEditView` shows a tip, but it's not visible in the preview.

Answer (score 2):

TipKit needs to be initialized for tips to show. You can initialize it inline for the preview:

```
#Preview {
    SettingEditView(editValue: .constant(DialogSetting(name: "Test Setting")))
        .task {
            try? await Tips.configure {
                DisplayFrequency(.immediate)
                DatastoreLocation(.applicationDefault)
            }
        }
}
```